ASP.NET Core OpenTelemetry integration with AWS XRay (No Collector)
We are running a dockerized ASP.NET Core app within AWS ECS Fargate. We want to add Open Telemetry to our project - I tried to add only corresponding code (libraries + injection + configuration) to set it up, assuming it would get AWS credentials by default (running inside AWS service) - but the traces don't make it up to AWS X-Ray. The code and docker file is as below. Note that running Console Exporter seems to be picking up the traces.

Can I avoid running otel collector as a separate service? (either as sidecar or a separate container)
Do you think anything misconfigured below?

Thanks in advance...
services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithTracing(builder =>
    {
        var options = new OpenTelemetryOptions();
        configuration.GetSection(OpenTelemetryOptions.OptionsKey).Bind(options);
        builder.SetResourceBuilder(ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
        .AddService(options.ServiceName, autoGenerateServiceInstanceId: false))
        .AddSource(sourceName.Name);
        if (options.TraceExportMode == TraceExportMode.OpenTelemetryAws)
        {
            builder.AddXRayTraceId();
            Sdk.SetDefaultTextMapPropagator(new AWSXRayPropagator());
        }
        switch (options.TraceExportMode)
        {
            case TraceExportMode.OpenTelemetryAws:
                {
                    builder.SetSampler(new AlwaysOnSampler()).AddOtlpExporter(o =>
                    {
                        o.Endpoint = new Uri(options.OpenTelemetryEndpoint);
                        o.Headers = options.OpenTelemetryHeaders;
                        o.TimeoutMilliseconds = options.OpenTelemetryTimoutMilliseconds;
                        o.ExportProcessorType = options.EnableBatching
                            ? ExportProcessorType.Batch
                            : ExportProcessorType.Simple;
                        o.BatchExportProcessorOptions = 
         BuildBatchExportProcessorOptions(options);
                    });
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    builder.SetSampler(new AlwaysOffSampler());
                    break;
                }
        }
   });
services.AddSingleton(_ => new ActivitySource(sourceName.Name ?? string.Empty, sourceName.Version?.ToString()));

Docker File is as below:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 as sdk
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-counters
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-dump
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-gcdump
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-stack
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace
FROM base AS final
## Copy dotnet tools
COPY --from=sdk /root/.dotnet/tools/ /opt/bin
ENV PATH="/opt/bin:${PATH}"
***** ..... *****

## Copy service
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./Artifacts/MyProject .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]


Yes, you can deploy ADOT Collector as sidecar with Cloudformation template in
https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/setup/ecs/cfn-for-ecs-fargate.
